# remap ctrl-shift-up -down (xubuntu, bash)

Tags: terminal, console, remapping

I'm using xubuntu 14.04 and trying to remap ctrl-shift-up/-down arrow key in vim in xfce-terminal (not gvim). Doing the same with left/right works fine. The keys are not mapped in some xfce-settings.

I unmapped all keys within the ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm. This helped to so far to enable shift-up and -down. ctrl-shift-up/-down is bound to the scroll-back buffer. I got stuck within the /etc/inputrc. Is this the right place to disable the key-code? I couldn't figure out any key bindings for this in there.

The mapping is working fine in xterm though. But xterm has no tabs and is quite complicated to configure otherwise. Is it possible to have ctrl-shift-up/-down passed to vim in the xfce-terminal somehow?

Thanks a lot, Leo

Answer (score 2):

You can install `lxterminal` which is similar to `xfce-terminal` but doesn't have this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install lxterminal
```

Comment: +1 - xfce's terminal has made some strange ("dumb") decisions about keys sometimes, aside from editing the source & rebuilding, this is probably the easiest. I'm looking for one that will map shift+up to scroll up a line, Qt Terminal does :)